# Using Windows explorer instead of X server for opening folders

Tags: cygwin

I've run the following lines:

```
startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

This switches the default GUI utility from Windows explorer to the x server in case I use this command `xdg-open .` for opening the current directory. I would like to switch back to Windows explorer. How can I carry it out?

Answer (score 0):

The X server do not open folders, it is a Graphical server for other programs, like xdg-open.

If you need to open explorer on the current directly, instead of xdg-open, just use

```
$ explorer . &
```

Or use its full path name

```
$ which explorer
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/explorer

$ /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/explorer . &
```